# Delete last record from SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I want to delete the last row from my table which I have 'no' is the auto number.
Could anyone help me please?

```
no | name | sex | phone|
1    Jack    m     343
2     tim    f     233
```

Comment: Well - what is the data ordered by ? Because the concept of the "last" row **requires"" some form of ordering - by date, by auto-ID, by name - anything - but **something** needs to define the ordering so that you can say which row is the **last row**......

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may try this

```
DELETE FROM table
WHERE  no = (SELECT Max(no) FROM table)
```

Comment: Thank for your help.

Comment: Just be careful if "no" column is not UNIQUE, you might end deleting more rows that you need.

Comment: @Rasnick: as mentioned above 'no' is auto number, so it is always unique.

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing it.

```
DELETE FROM TableName
WHERE  ColumnName IN (SELECT TOP 1 ColumnName 
                      FROM   TableName
                      ORDER  BY ColumnName DESC);
```

Or you can use this with precaution

```
DELETE FROM TableName
WHERE  ColumnName = Ident_current('TableName')
```

Note: This only works if that table has enabled [Auto-increment](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_autoincrement.asp).

Answer (score 0):

Another Way of doing it (since [no] column is already numbered):

```
          ;WITH CTE
          AS 
          (
          SELECT MAX(no)  OVER(ORDER BY no ASC) AS MaxDelete FROM TableName
          )
          DELETE FROM TableName WHERE no = MaxDelete
```